# Behavior of bitwise shift operators when right operand is negative

Tags: java, c#, c++, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

In C & C++, if right operand is negative when using `>>` and `<<` (shift right & shift left operator), behavior of program is undefined.
Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int s(9);
    std::cout<<(s<<-3);
}
```

g++ gives following warning:

```
[Warning] left shift count is negative [enabled by default]
```

MSVS 2010 gives following warning:

```
warning c4293: '<<' : shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
```

Now I am curious about what happens in Java and C#?

I've tried following program

```
class left_shift_nagative
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a=3;
        System.out.println(a<<-3);
        System.out.println(a>>-3);
    }
}
```

Outcome of program:

```
1610612736
0
```

C#'s turn:

```
namespace left_shift_nagative
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int s = 3;
            Console.WriteLine(s << -3);
            Console.WriteLine(s >> -3); 
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1610612736
0
```

How the output 1610612736 comes? What is happening here? What the Java Language Specification (JLS) and C# Language Specification or standard says about this? How << and >> operator works when negative shift count is given in Java & C#? How I got output 0 when right shift is used? I am really getting confused.

Comment: It uses bits. If you check -3 in bits it's like `.... 1101`. The dots are a lot of `1111 1111 1111`
Shifting right will shift `0011` to `0000` as it can't do anything after that.

Comment: I was just reading a post by Eric Lippert here. #8 mentions the shift operators. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answer about the Java part (can't speak for C# but it is probably the same).

The shift operators `>>` and `<<` are defined in JLS [section 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19). Quoting (emphasis mine):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). **The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive**.

Therefore, when you are shifting by `-3`, it is exactly as if you were shifting by `-3 & 0x1f`, which is 29 (only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used).

- The result of `a << -3` is then `2^29 * a`; for `a = 3`, this is `1610612736`.
- The result of `a >> -3` is then `floor(a / 2^29)`; for `a = 3`, this is `0`.

Note that when the promoted type of the left-operand is `long`, and not `int`, the mask value used is `0x3f` (only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used).

Answer (score 1):

### For C#

From the C# spec Section 7.9 -

> For the predefined operators, the number of bits to shift is computed as follows:
>
> - When the type of `x` is `int` or `uint`, the shift count is given by the low-order 5 bits of `count`. In other words, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x1F`
> - When the type of `x` is `long` or `ulong`, the shift count is given by the low-order 6 bits of `count`. In other words, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x3F`

This means that the sign of the shift is ignored. In fact as pointed out by Jon Skeet in the annotated spec, the following code will wrap after `i == 31` due to the bit masking defined by the spec.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue >> i);
}
```